Orientation on a Manifold and Charts
Let $(U,\phi)$ be a chart on a smooth orientable manifold $M$ with oriented atlas $\mathcal{A}=\{(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in A}$.
In general, the chart $(U,\phi)$ may be or not consistently oriented with such an atlas (there are two possible orientations on $U$). Is it true that if $(U,\phi)$ is consistently oriented with some chart of the atlas $\mathcal{A}$, then it must be consistently oriented with any other chart of $\mathcal{A}$?
My attempt: yes, by the formula:
$$
\frac{\partial(x^1,\dots,x^n)}{\partial (z^1_\beta,\dots,z^n_\beta)}= \frac{\partial(x^1,\dots,x^n)}{\partial (z^1_\alpha,\dots,z^n_\alpha)} \cdot \left (\frac{\partial(z^1_\alpha,\dots,z^n_\alpha)}{\partial (z^1_\beta,\dots,z^n_\beta)} \right )
$$
Is my argument correct?

Yeah its the chain rule combined with product rule for determinants.
